# Securely access Amazon S3 static website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, certificate

Can someone explain why,  when Amazon S3 uses a wildcard SSL certificate, you can not access the static website through https?

Comment: there are billions of buckets on s3 and you can't expect Amazon to create cert with complete subject name and also buckets can be access in many different ways such as   bucket-name.s3.region.amazonaws.com, s3.region.amazonaws.com/bucketname etc , you cloudfront to use i your own cert and keep s3 as an origin.

Answer (score 2):

For accessing static website over https you would need to user cloudfront on top of your bucket.

for installing a SSL certificate you would need a server, well S3 is just for storage, you cannot install SSL certificate over S3.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/